# What permissions do I need to read items from a list via REST - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I'm trying to read the items from a list via REST within a SharePoint-hosted app, but in response I get **403 - Forbidden** so I wonder which permissions do i need, I thought that **web - read** in the appManifest would be enough but it seems like it doesn´t, or maybe i missing something else, the endpoint i'm using is `http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Test')/items`, by the way I'm using angular 2 **http module** for this, like so:

```
 private url= "https://URL/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('test')/items";  // URL to web API
          getItems(): Observable<any[]> {
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');

            return this.http.get(this.url, {headers: headers})
                            .map(this.extractData)
                            .catch(this.handleError);
          }

         private extractData(res: Response) {
           let body = res.json();
           console.log(body);
           return body || { };
        }
```

So if somebody knows what's happening and how can I get the data it will be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44129/discussion-on-question-by-emmanuel-villegas-what-permissions-do-i-need-to-read-i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access host data from a SharePoint-hosted add-in, you must use the `AppContextSite` endpoint, or the cross-domain library, `RequestExecutor`.  The former can be done by changing your url to the following:

```
appUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/GetByTitle('test')/items?@target='" + encodeURIComponent(hostUrl) + "'"
```

More details, including how to use the cross-domain library, can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx).